# Run async in parallel with only one callback

Tags: node.js, multithreading, rest, asynchronous, callback

I have a question which might be silly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm gettin 1 000 results from REST endpoint. However the results are tokenized and split into 100 element arrays. After I process 100 elements I need a callback to get next 100.

Below is my code for running through array

```
  async.eachSeries(body.hits.hits, function(hit, loopHit) {
      check_order(hit, loopHit);
  }, function done() {
      // get next array
  });
```

The reason reason I do async here is because I need to know when I complete all 100 results (function done).

The result is - I need to run all 100 elements one by one (in check_order I connect to different REST point and wait for callback there), and I would like to run on all of them simultaneously, and once the last is completed I would like to get next array from first endpoint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is missing in the async:

```
  async.eachSeries(body.hits.hits, function(hit, loopHit) {
      check_order(hit);
      loopHit();
  }, function done() {
      // get next array
  });
```

And also you are giving the callback loopHit in the checkHit function.

Comment: this would result in calling a callback before function check_order completes so yes - on one hand it will execute on all of the hits in the way designed but on other it will not give a chance for a last one to complete and then trigger a callback;